# Should I keep hold of 'useless' items?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have lots of 'rubbish' from enemy drops, as my current equipment is better than anything I've found so far (only a few hours in).

Is there any reason to keep hold of these items, from Dark Souls I you couldn't sell items, can you now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if you progressed far enough in the game, you could sell items in Dark Souls I and you can do so in Dark Souls II. Eventually, you'll make your way over to No Man's Wharf, where you'll find an NPC named Gavlan behind a door on the second floor of a house (location may differ for SotFS). You can sell items to Gavlan in return for souls.

There is also no need to throw items away since your carry weight only applies to weapons and armor that you have equipped, not everything in your inventory.

Comment: Just wanna note that Gavlan would only be at No Man's Wharf once, after that he'd move to somewhere else, so dump everything you have on him right then and there, you won't meet him again any time soon

Comment: Gavlan goes to a cave in Harvest Valley near the first bonfire after that, then a room above the first bonfire in the Doors of Pharros once more. He stays there indefinitely. I recommend buying poison arrows from him in Pharros to use in Iron Keep.

Comment: Note that you can easily hit the inventory item limit in NG+2, even if the item weight isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "junk" weapons to craft special boss weapons using the soul items obtained for defeating them. Boss weapons need an upgraded weapon of a specific type -- greatsword, ultra greatsword, whip, etc -- as well as the boss's soul involved in the recipe. Keeping a weapon of each type is a pretty good idea if you don't know any of the boss weapons' attributes, in case you find that you want to make a particular one. You'll be able to craft these special weapons once you talk to specific NPCs.

EDIT: Nevermind, in DkS2 you only need the boss soul to make the item in question. I was thinking of DkS1.

Comment: This applies only to Dark Souls 1, boss weapons in Dark Souls 2 only require the relevant boss soul and equivalent price in souls.

Comment: Wait, really? Damn, now I feel dumb, I guess I had just always had the weapons on hand in DkS2 out of habit so I did not notice.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind some items that may seem like junk are actually useful in some way or another. You may regret selling them, or not live long enough to.

You also have the item box, which you can access from any bonfire from the start of the game. Instead of selling your extra items, consider simply storing them for later.